# I want each word that is being generated by var text to be within individual <span> tags

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, var

I currently generate text when my website loads here https://www.droolstudios.co.uk/home. I'm now making some changes and would like each individual work to generate within a `<span></span>`.

HTML

```js
        var i = 0;
        var txt = 'Branding. Websites. Design & Creative Services. We turn your vision into reality.';
        //var txt = 'Turning your creative visions into reality with ease and care.... and we also do dog sitting.';

        function typeWriter() {
            if (i < txt.length) {
                document.getElementsByClassName('js-typewrite')[0].innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
                i++;
                setTimeout(typeWriter, 95);
           
            }
        }

        setTimeout(typeWriter, 1000);
```

```html
    <section>
            <div class="home-intro">
                <div class="sub-heading">
                    <span class="typewrite anim-typewrite js-typewrite"></span>
                </div>

            </div>
        </section>
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: you want generate html? the value in var text becomes each word in a span and all spans inside a same div?

Comment: for example **Design & Creative Services.** is 4 words  Design, &, Creative and  Services.      a word is something delimited by space

Comment: Yes, exactly right.

Answer (score 2):

i generate new var result with each word of var txt embbed by span tag, then you just generate your html where you want.

```
var txt = 'Branding. Websites. Design & Creative Services. We turn your vision into reality.';

var sp0 = txt.split(" "); // split by space

var result = sp0.map( (w) => "<span>" + w + "</span>").join("");
console.log(result)
```

the `join` command transforms the array in one line, if you want to keep an array, dont do that command

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```js
        var i = 0;
        var txt = 'Branding. Websites. Design & Creative Services. We turn your vision into reality.';
        //var txt = 'Turning your creative visions into reality with ease and care.... and we also do dog sitting.';
        let splitted=txt.split(" ");

        function typeWriter() {
            if (i < splitted.length) {
                document.getElementsByClassName('js-typewrite')[0].innerHTML += splitted[i]+ " ";
                i++;
                setTimeout(typeWriter, 395);
           
            }
        }

        setTimeout(typeWriter, 1000);
```

```html
    <section>
            <div class="home-intro">
                <div class="sub-heading">
                    <span class="typewrite anim-typewrite js-typewrite"></span>
                </div>

            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: In a way yes, but this doesn't place each individual word inside a span. I guess a solution would be have the spans already created and rather the html being generated, it already exists and is displayed? what do you think?

Comment: Maybe answer of @Frenchy is more similar way that you are looking for